# VS 2015 suddenly complaining about Newtonsoft.Json version compatibility

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, json.net

I have a complex solution which suddenly -- and I mean suddenly, for days it was compiling just fine and the next moment it wasn't -- started complaining about Newtonsoft version compatibilities:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1705  Assembly 'UploadFramework' with identity
>   'UploadFramework, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' which has a higher
>   version than referenced assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' with identity
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'  UploadProcessor..NET Framework
>   4.6   C:\Programming\ConnellCampaigns\src\UploadProcessor\batch\EnvelopeSalutationJob.cs  341 Active

I am totally at a loss as to how to fix this...as so far as I can tell, nothing has changed in the code base.

However, I had just done a "reorganize usings" across the entire solution, which modified quite a few files. OTOH, as soon as I ran into this problem, I immediately reverted all the changes -- thank goodness for git! -- so I should be back to where I am.

But I'm not...

Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Additional Info

I should've mentioned that the project.json file for UploadFramework has this line in it:

```
"Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.8"
```

There's a blue squiggly line under the 6.0.8 which, when you hover the mouse over it, says that the project ended up with version 9.0.1. I don't understand how I can specifically define a particular version, and end up with a more recent one. Perhaps that's a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: If you reverted all files it should just be a matter of running "Clean..." on your solution.

Comment: First thing I tried after reverting. For whatever reason, it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two different versions of the Newtonsoft assembly references in your solution. You can use the "consolidate" option in the nuget package manager and you should be fine.

If it do not work after a revert: clean is the first thing to try, sometimes you also need to clean up the /packages folder - you might have multiple folder for Newtonsoft these. Simply delete the version you are not working. Then the solution should build again.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you! If I could upvote this more than just once I would do it, as you saved me from missing a significant deadline. Not to mention that I've now learned about solution-wide nuget package management, which I was not aware of.

Comment: Glad I could help you!